# How to stop disappearing the dropped when I want to disappear the source drag items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have drag items inside of the Bootstrap button collapse. I click the button and it's show my all drag items. And I can also one item and drop my specific place. But problem is when I click on button for disappear my other items, it's also disappear my drop item too.

HTML:

```
</div>
<div class='buttonclass'>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.draggable'>ClickMe and Drag Item</button>
</div>

<div id="draggable1" class="collapse draggable">
  <p class="ui-widget-header">drag and drop 1</p>
</div>

<div id="draggable2" class="collapse draggable">
  <p>drag and drop 2</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Demo code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/labu4bd/xkb71uka/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is even though you changed the relative position of the draggable object, it still belongs to the dropdown hierarchy, so it will respond to the close event of the button

I'm not terribly familiar with jQuery.UI, but there should be some way to clone the object you are dragging. Or if you only want one instance of the draggable element, there is a somewhat trivial way make the element a child of the droppable area using jQuery. --Just remember to work with the elements inside the draggable because you've made the draggable element collapsable when the button is clicked.

Think about the elements you're working with and how they are in relation to the rest of the markup, not the position of where they are on the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did with the clone of the dragging object. but it make almost same problem. you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/labu4bd/xkb71uka/2/)

Comment: That's because you are cloning the draggable element which is also the collapsible element. You need to clone the draggable's children: `$(ui.draggable).children().clone().appendTo($(this));`